# Function uploadData not found in contract SmartContract - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: json, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, smartcontracts

I'm altering the fabcar version of hyperledger fabric and wrote some functions. When I executed, I got an error mentioned below (command mentioned below is of shell script)

```
$ peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n cloud $PEER_CONN_PARMS --isInit -c '{"function":"uploadData","Args":["DATA1","ID12345","/home/samplefile___pdf","3"]}'
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: Function uploadData not found in contract SmartContract"
```

Below is the chaincode (abstractly mentioned)

```
type SmartContract struct {
    contractapi.Contract
}

type Data struct {
    Owner  string `json:"owner"`
    File string `json:"file"`
    FileChunkNumber string `json:"filechunknumber"`
    SHA256 string `json:"sha256"`
}

// Uploads new data to the world state with given details
func (s *SmartContract) uploadData(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, args []string) error {
    /*...*/
}
```

I don't get where to alter the changes

Comment: Is the chaincode "Invoke" function redirecting your call to the above function, like its does in fabcar, or marbles example chaincodes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have updated the chaincode version number or chaincode name while installation and instantiation. (1.4.6)

Have you tried pre-existing functions of the chaincode,Are they working with your invoke command.
If not,please follow this invoke command:

```
 peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n cloud $PEER_CONN_PARMS -c '{"Args":["uploadData","DATA1","ID12345","/home/samplefile___pdf","3"]}'
```

Comment: It's actually the problem with function naming convention, in my case. I capitalised the first letter and it worked. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem before; there can be 2 possible errors:

1. Fabric might be using the old chaincode docker image; hence try
   deleting that image and re-create the docker image with the updated
   chaincode.
2. There might be some problem in the body of your uploadData function (could be a syntactical or logical error) which you'll have to debug.

Hope that helps!

Comment: My bad!! I think function is not exported due to its starting lowercase letter. I capitalised the first letter and it worked. Thank you for your time

Comment: Oh yes, true. Using capital letter for any package object in go exports it automatically!